# Set of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

I am working on a homework problem which asks me about the Set of a singular $n\times n$ matrix. specifically whether it is a vector space. I looked in the glossary of the book and searched online and no where could I find a definition of the Set of a matrix. What is the definition of a matrix set? Is it just the column space?

Comment: Presumably the problem means (for a given $n$) the set whose elements are the singular $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: oh you are exactly correct, I misread the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're studying the set $S \subset \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ of singular matrices.

The matrices:

$$ A=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \\
0 &  &  & 0\\
 \end{array} \right)$$ and

$$ B=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \\
0 &  &  & 1\\
 \end{array} \right)$$

are singular (elements of $S$). What do you think of $A+B$?